# Laravel websockets package connection refused?

Tags: php, websocket, laravel

I using laravel websocket package aspusher replacement. First this ubuntu was not allowing to access the port `6001` then I add Inboud securoty group rule on aws . Now it is allowing to access the port but still not allowing to flow data thorug these porst and return this error.

```
pusher.min.js:8 WebSocket connection to 'ws://52.64.101.38:6001/app/ABCDEF?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I think I need to do more settings on aws but what I don't know.

It is also giving Authentication errors see screenshot
[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UmUi.png)

Comment: I tried all methods highlite in it nothing working have you seen screenshot?

Comment: The screenshot is a separate question and has nothing to do with your websocket problem. As discussed in the linked post, you need to start a service listening on that port.

Comment: Listening channel is working fine but problem is with broadcasting . It wont allow boradcasting